# Error in desktop mail client application in C# | Smtp error

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, gmail, smtpclient

I was building a desktop mail client using C#
This application works fine in my friend's pc but not working in my pc.
Its showing me a list of exception.
Pls help me.

System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'smtp.gmail.com'

list of exceptions are here
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/7781fb98-9c5e-4b3c-b699-e9ff92da75eb/

Comment: Sounds like a DNS issue to me

Comment: Are you using a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a proxy, you should configure your *app.config* file like this:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
        <proxy usessystemdefault="False" 
            proxyaddress="http://your-proxy-name.domain.com:port-number-if-any"
            bypassonlocal="True"
            autoDetect="False" />
   </defaultProxy> 
</system.net>
```